# use css file only if viewport is X?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a css file that I want him to be used only if the viewport is 1024 and higher.

how can I declare my css file to be loaded only and based on a viewport i'll decide about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the media attribute.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 1024px)" href="style.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
 <style>


             @media only screen and (min-device-width: 1024px) 
            {

              Whatever you want for css...

            }


            </style>
```